# jQuery - good solution for "easy parsing" of html string

Tags: jquery

​​I have the following html string (var jsonHtmlString) returned as json in a jquery get request and need to parse the html to return an array of objects with using the info below. There's probably an easy way to do this but I haven't been able to find it. I'm hoping someone might be able to recommend an "easy parsing" solution (and if you use an online tool (e.g. plnkr.co) to easily seeing the parsing as you test your js code)?

I've included what the jQuery selector value should return on each line of the mapped object. Thanks!

```
var jsonHtmlString = '<div class="search-result-srch box"> <span class="number">1.</span>
    <a href="/Practice/Detail.aspx?docid=18600&mode=search&p=Tools-@-Technology">The Continuous Learning Technology Stack: Thinking outside the LMS</a>
    <br />
    <div title="Research Report" class="description rr">This report introduces the Continuous Learning Technology Stack, or the sum of technologies that can be leveraged for enabling continuous learning within organizations. </div>
    <div class="pracsub"> <span class="col1-a">Practice:</span> <span class="col1-b"><strong>Tools & Technology</strong></span> <span class="col2-a">Subject:</span> <span class="col2-b"><strong>Learning Tech</strong></span> </div>
    <div class="pracsub top-blue-brdr"> <span class="col1-a">Access:</span> <span class="col1-b">Member</span> <span class="col2-a">Published:</span> <span class="col2-b">09/02/2015</span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> <span class="col1-a">Type:</span> <span class="col1-b">Research Report</span> </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="search-result-srch box"> <span class="number">2.</span>
    <a href="/Practice/Detail.aspx?docid=18817&mode=search&p=Learning-@-Development">Business Case for Investing Beyond the LMS (editable PPT)</a>
    <br />
    <div title="Performance Support" class="description ps">This editable PowerPoint template guides you through the process of building and presenting a business case for investing in continuous learning—beyond the LMS.</div>
    <div class="pracsub"> <span class="col1-a">Practice:</span> <span class="col1-b"><strong>Learning & Development</strong></span> <span class="col2-a">Subject:</span> <span class="col2-b"><strong>Informal Learning</strong></span> </div>
    <div class="pracsub top-blue-brdr"> <span class="col1-a">Access:</span> <span class="col1-b">Complimentary</span> <span class="col2-a">Published:</span> <span class="col2-b">08/26/2015</span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> <span class="col1-a">Type:</span> <span class="col1-b">Performance Support</span> </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>';

var items = parseHtml(jsonHtmlString); 

function parseHtml(html) { 
    var items = $(div.search-result-srch); // array of object for each div class="search-result-srchbox" 
    items.map((item) => {
            return {
                title: $(item)('a'), // The Continuous Learning..., Business Case for...
                description: $(item)('.description'), // This report introduces..., This editable PowerPoint...
                practice: $(item)('.col1-b').innerText, // Tools & Technology, Learning & Development
                subject: $(item)('.col2-b').innerText, // Learning Tech, Informal Learning
                access: $(item)('.pracsub .col2-b').innerText, // Member, Complimentary
                publishDate: $(item)('.pracsub .col2-b').innerText, // 09/02/2015, 08/26/2015
                type: $(item)('.pracsub .col1-b:last-of-type').innerText, // Research Report, Performance Support
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: When you say "parse," are you trying to do something like this? https://plnkr.co/edit/dRugzmUOXiBGiiDpwoNP?p=preview

Comment: That's exactly what I mean! Thanks. I was missing the .find reference. One question though. Where you have selected the items array, var items = element.find('div.search-result-srch'), aren't the items returned already "wrapped" in jquery (since the $ object was used in the initial selector,  let element = $(html)) . Why then do you need to reference $(item) when iterating over each item in the map loop? (instead of just using item.find())?  Also, do you want to make the link to your plnk the answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can construct a jQuery object given a chunk of HTML. Like this `$('<whatever>Stuff</whatever>');`

I wrapped your HTML string in a `div` so that your existing code more or less works without modification. After getting the jQuery object into `element` your code was almost correct.

```
  let items = parseHtml('<div>' + jsonHtmlString + '</div>');    
  function parseHtml(html) {
    let element = $(html);
    var items = element.find('div.search-result-srch'); // array of object for each div class="search-result-srchbox" 
    let map = items.map((index, item) => {
      return {
        title: $(item).find('a').text(), // The Continuous Learning..., Business Case for...
        description: $(item).find('.description').text(), // This report introduces..., This editable PowerPoint...
        practice: $(item).find('.col1-b').text(), // Tools & Technology, Learning & Development
        subject: $(item).find('.col2-b').text(), // Learning Tech, Informal Learning
        access: $(item).find('.pracsub .col2-b').text(), // Member, Complimentary
        publishDate: $(item).find('.pracsub .col2-b').text(), // 09/02/2015, 08/26/2015
        type: $(item).find('.pracsub .col1-b:last-of-type').text(), // Research Report, Performance Support
      }
    });

    return $.makeArray(map);
  }
```

You asked in a comment above

> Why then do you need to reference $(item) when iterating over each item in the map loop?

From jQuery's docs for `map`:

> Type: Function( Integer index, Element domElement ) => Object
>   A function object that will be invoked for each element in the current set.

Notice that the element is a *DOM* element, not a jQuery object. So we need to call $(item) to wrap it as a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a `parseHTML` method already. You just need to run that and then map through the results correctly. Sample below:

```
var jsonHtmlString = `<div class="search-result-srch box"> <span class="number">1.</span>
<a href="/Practice/Detail.aspx?docid=18600&mode=search&p=Tools-@-Technology">The Continuous Learning Technology Stack: Thinking outside the LMS</a>
<br />
<div title="Research Report" class="description rr">This report introduces the Continuous Learning Technology Stack, or the sum of technologies that can be leveraged for enabling continuous learning within organizations. </div>
<div class="pracsub"> <span class="col1-a">Practice:</span> <span class="col1-b"><strong>Tools & Technology</strong></span> <span class="col2-a">Subject:</span> <span class="col2-b"><strong>Learning Tech</strong></span> </div>
<div class="pracsub top-blue-brdr"> <span class="col1-a">Access:</span> <span class="col1-b">Member</span> <span class="col2-a">Published:</span> <span class="col2-b">09/02/2015</span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div> <span class="col1-a">Type:</span> <span class="col1-b">Research Report</span> </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="search-result-srch box"> <span class="number">2.</span>
<a href="/Practice/Detail.aspx?docid=18817&mode=search&p=Learning-@-Development">Business Case for Investing Beyond the LMS (editable PPT)</a>
<br />
<div title="Performance Support" class="description ps">This editable PowerPoint template guides you through the process of building and presenting a business case for investing in continuous learning—beyond the LMS.</div>
<div class="pracsub"> <span class="col1-a">Practice:</span> <span class="col1-b"><strong>Learning & Development</strong></span> <span class="col2-a">Subject:</span> <span class="col2-b"><strong>Informal Learning</strong></span> </div>
<div class="pracsub top-blue-brdr"> <span class="col1-a">Access:</span> <span class="col1-b">Complimentary</span> <span class="col2-a">Published:</span> <span class="col2-b">08/26/2015</span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div> <span class="col1-a">Type:</span> <span class="col1-b">Performance Support</span> </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>`;

var htmled = $.parseHTML(jsonHtmlString);

var listOfObjects = htmled.map(item => {
  if ($(item).hasClass('search-result-srch')) {
    return {
      title: $(item).find('a').text(), // The Continuous Learning..., Business Case for...
      description: $(item).find('.description').text(), // This report introduces..., This editable PowerPoint...
      practice: $(item).find('.col1-b').text(), // Tools & Technology, Learning & Development
      subject: $(item).find('.col2-b').text(), // Learning Tech, Informal Learning
      access: $(item).find('.pracsub .col2-b').text(), // Member, Complimentary
    publishDate: $(item).find('.pracsub .col2-b').text(), // 09/02/2015, 08/26/2015
      type: $(item).find('.pracsub .col1-b:last-of-type').text(), // Research Report, Performance Support
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm using an older version of jquery that doesnt include parseHtml. Aquinas answer works for what I need, but he hasn't added it as the answer. Thanks.